# Different output when using \input command

Tags: input

Suppose, we need to create a block for signatures for a contract consisting of 2 horizontal lines and names below them. `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[.45\textwidth]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[.45\textwidth]{\hrulefill}

\noindent\makebox[.45\textwidth][l]{Director 1} \hfill\makebox[.45\textwidth][l]{Director 2}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]
Everything is fine. But when I move the code into a separate file `signature.tex` and put a reference to it into the main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\input{signature.tex}
\end{document}
```

The name of the second person becomes shifted to the left:

[image]

What's wrong? How to fix? Using TeX Live 2017 on Windows XP.

Comment: Add a `%` in the last line of the input file: like `...{Director 2}%`. Or alternatively add `\unskip` after the input line, like `\input{signature.tex}\unskip`.

Comment: @Troy This fixed the issue. What was happening? Can you put an explanation with solution to the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `\input` is adding a space at the end of the input content, here the `Director 1....Director 2` line.

You can avoid this in two ways: 
**Either** add a `%` on the last line of your input file `signature.tex`, like:

```
\noindent\makebox[.45\textwidth]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[.45\textwidth]{\hrulefill}

\noindent\makebox[.45\textwidth][l]{Director 1} \hfill\makebox[.45\textwidth][l]{Director 2}%
```

**or** add `\unskip` directly after the `\input` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\input{signature.tex}\unskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

(frame added to show page margins)

---

Harald explains it well [in a comment here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/space-inserted-after-input-call?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#comment33737_18018):

> It doesn't matter if the final line ends with a newline or not. The point is, TeX sees the file as consisting of a bunch of lines. As part of the tokenization process, a character whose code is the value of `\endlinechar` is inserted at the end of each line (except when the line ends with a comment or a control sequence).