# How do I trim a text taken from a file by \input?

Tags: input

Here is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, \input{name.txt}!
\end{document}
```

My file `name.txt` has a single line `Jeff\n` (with EOL at the end).

It's rendered to: `Hello, Jeff !`. How do I remove the space after `Jeff`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Space inserted after "\input" call](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/space-inserted-after-input-call). Especially see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18880/224762) answer.

Comment: You could also try using `\!` to step back one character, as it were.

Comment: or just `\unskip` before !

Comment: @Ingmar `\!` is not the same size as a word space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Yes, my bad. It's actually `-0,16667em`, so it'd probably take 6 of them. Other solutions are certainly more elegant.